# SearchBox in GWT Maps V3 Api (branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api version 3.8.1)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I am develop an app using GWT Maps Api V3. I try create Place search box  like example of Google Maps JavaScript API(link [Place search box - Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)  )

I have viewed the javascript code, they create SeachBox by using `google.maps.places.SearchBox` But in GWT Maps Api V3 ( version 3.8.1, [GWT-Maps-V3-Api](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) ), there is no class name SearchBox. I think i can create a SearchBox by using `autocomplete` and a html input field. But i can not place my nput field inside my map. So, my question is: what is the right way to create a SearchBox with GWT Maps V3 Api?
Thank for any help.

Comment: you want to put another textbox on Map ?

Comment: actually, I want know right way to create SearchBox in GWT Maps V3 Api

Comment: You need to use a wrapper to be able to use Google Maps API v3 with GWT. There are some available. You can search them online.

Comment: i am using GWT Maps Api V3 (https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using  method (on branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api version 3.8.1)

> void com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapWidget.setControls(ControlPosition controlPosition, Widget widget)

First, i create a textbox

```
private TextBox placeSearchTextField = new TextBox();
```

and use setControls:

```
mapWidget.setControls(ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT, placeSearchTextField );
```

add autocomple

```
private void drawAutoComplete() {

    Element element = placeSearchTextField.getElement();

    AutocompleteType[] types = new AutocompleteType[2];
    types[0] = AutocompleteType.ESTABLISHMENT;
    types[1] = AutocompleteType.GEOCODE;

    AutocompleteOptions options = AutocompleteOptions.newInstance();
    options.setTypes(types);

    final Autocomplete autoComplete = Autocomplete.newInstance(element, options);

    autoComplete.addPlaceChangeHandler(new PlaceChangeMapHandler() {
      public void onEvent(PlaceChangeMapEvent event) {        

        PlaceResult result = autoComplete.getPlace();

        PlaceGeometry geomtry = result.getGeometry();
        LatLng center = geomtry.getLocation();

        GWT.log("place changed center=" + center);
      }
    });

    mapWidget.getMap().addBoundsChangeHandler(new BoundsChangeMapHandler() {
        public void onEvent(BoundsChangeMapEvent event) {
          LatLngBounds bounds = mapWidget.getMap().getBounds();
          autoComplete.setBounds(bounds);
        }
      });
}
```

with some css, I get the result
[image]

Comment: Hey, but from where drawAutoComplete() get called..?

Comment: inside method onModuleLoad(). You could view some example on GitHub branflake2267 project website.